# Write info message in app.log file using yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app

I want to write info message in app.log file for debugging. For that I am using that code in web.php file:-

```
      log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],

                  [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['info'],
                    'categories' => ['orders'],
                    'logFile' => '@app/runtime/logs/requests.log',
                    'maxFileSize' => 1024 * 2,
                    'maxLogFiles' => 20,
                ],
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['info'],
                    'categories' => ['pushNotifications'],
                    'logFile' => '@app/runtime/logs/Orders/notification.log',
                    'maxFileSize' => 1024 * 2,
                    'maxLogFiles' => 50,
                ],

            ],
     ]
```

and in my controller file I am using that code :-

```
   Yii::info($valuerendom, 'orders');
```

but no message is written in .log file.

Thank you,

Comment: It looks ok. Check if application has got write permission for the selected folders.

Comment: @Bizley I gave write permission ,but not working

Comment: Check server logs, maybe something is wrong in different place. Try to create file in the log folder using PHP.

Comment: @Bizley I check Apache error log but no error there , Thank you

Comment: Set debugger break point on FileTarget::export() method and see what happens.

Comment: @TomaszKane I debuged value its going to BaseYii :: info()   and also correctly print value Logger.php:: log() but its not going to FileTarget::export()

Comment: If you have long-running applications (maybe those push notifications?), you need to lower `flushInterval` and `exportInterval` from the default settings in order to see fast logging. Else Yii would collect log files until X items are hit and export just then (or on application exit, whichever comes first)

Comment: Did you succeed ? Maybe try to add info level to all your configuration element