# Why is nothing logged in app.log in Yii2?

Tags: yii2, yii2-log

I have the same problem that is asked here:

[Write info message in app.log file using yii2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41692592/write-info-message-in-app-log-file-using-yii2)

But there is no solution at that topic.
Apache user have write permission to logs folder. I don't know why logging doesn't work.

Any comments?

Here's what I have in config/main.php file:

```
'log' => [
        'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
        'targets' => [
            [
                'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
            ],

            [
                'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                'levels' => ['info'],
                'categories' => ['records'],
                'logFile' => '@app/runtime/logs/records.log',
                'maxFileSize' => 1024 * 2,
                'maxLogFiles' => 20,
            ],
        ],
    ],
```

and what I use to write to log file:

```
Yii::info('Sample text.', 'records');
```

Comment: Do you set log in config files?

Comment: there might be several reasons other than the writes, you might need to check the error logs on your domain cpanel if anything is being reported there

Comment: @tigrasti I added what is in config file to the question body.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure your web server has write access to `runtime/logs/record.log`

If you are using apache or nginx above linux :

```
cd /to/your/app-path/
chown user:www-data runtime/ -R
chmod 775 user:www-data runtime/ -R
```